# Python pool.map function completes but leaves zombies

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I've been having an issue where pool.map leaves processes even after pool.terminate is called. I've looked for solutions but they all seems to have some other issue like recursively calling the map function or another process that interferes with the multiprocessing.

So my code imports 2 NETCDF files and processes the data in them using different calculations. These take up a lot of time (several 6400x6400 arrays) so I tried to multi process my code. The multiprocessing works and the first time I run my code it takes 2.5 minutes (down from 8), but every time my code finishes running the memory usage by Spyder never goes back down and it leaves extra python processes in the Windows task manager. My code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import netCDF4
import math
from math import sin, cos
import logging
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
import time

start=time.time()
format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO, datefmt="%H:%M:%S")
logging.info("Here we go!")
path = "DATAPATH"
geopath = "DATAPATH"
f = netCDF4.Dataset(path)
f.set_auto_maskandscale(False)

f2 = netCDF4.Dataset(geopath)
i5lut=f.groups['observation_data'].variables['I05_brightness_temperature_lut'][:]
i4lut=f.groups['observation_data'].variables['I05_brightness_temperature_lut'][:]
I5= f.groups['observation_data'].variables['I05'][:]
I4= f.groups['observation_data'].variables['I04'][:]
I5=i5lut[I5]
I4=i4lut[I4]
I4Quality= f.groups['observation_data'].variables['I04_quality_flags'][:]
I5Quality= f.groups['observation_data'].variables['I05_quality_flags'][:]
I3= f.groups['observation_data'].variables['I03']
I2= f.groups['observation_data'].variables['I02']
I1= f.groups['observation_data'].variables['I01']
I1.set_auto_scale(True)
I2.set_auto_scale(True)
I3.set_auto_scale(True)
I1=I1[:]
I2=I2[:]
I3=I3[:]

lats = f2.groups['geolocation_data'].variables['latitude'][:]
lons = f2.groups['geolocation_data'].variables['longitude'][:]
solarZen = f2.groups['geolocation_data'].variables['solar_zenith'][:]
sensorZen= solarZen = f2.groups['geolocation_data'].variables['sensor_zenith'][:]
solarAz = f2.groups['geolocation_data'].variables['solar_azimuth'][:]
sensorAz= solarZen = f2.groups['geolocation_data'].variables['sensor_azimuth'][:]
def kernMe(i, j, band):
    if i<250 or j<250:
        return -1
    else:
        return np.mean(band[i-250:i+250:1,j-250:j+250:1])
def thread_me(arr):
    start1=arr[0]
    end1=arr[1]
    start2=arr[2]
    end2=arr[3]
    logging.info("Im starting at: %d to %d, %d to %d" %(start1, end1, start2, end2))
    points = []
    avg = np.mean(I4)
    for i in range(start1,end1):
        for j in range (start2,end2):

            if solarZen[i,j]>=90:
                if not (I5[i,j]<265 and I4[i,j]<295):#
                    if I4[i,j]>320 and I4Quality[i,j]==0:
                        points.append([lons[i,j],lats[i,j], 1])
                    elif I4[i,j]>300 and I5[i,j]-I4[i,j]>10:
                        points.append([lons[i,j],lats[i,j], 2])
                    elif I4[i,j] == 367 and I4Quality ==9:
                        points.append([lons[i,j],lats[i,j, 3]])
            else:

                if not ((I1[i,j]>I2[i,j]>I3[i,j]) or (I5[i,j]<265 or (I1[i,j]+I2[i,j]>0.9 and I5[i,j]<295) or 
                         (I1[i,j]+I2[i,j]>0.7 and I5[i,j]<285))):
                    if not (I1[i,j]+I2[i,j] > 0.6 and I5[i,j]<285 and I3[i,j]>0.3 and I3[i,j]>I2[i,j] and I2[i,j]>0.25 and I4[i,j]<=335):
                         thetaG= (cos(sensorZen[i,j]*(math.pi/180))*cos(solarZen[i,j]*(math.pi/180)))-(sin(sensorZen[i,j]*(math.pi/180))*sin(solarZen[i,j]*(math.pi/180))*cos(sensorAz[i,j]*(math.pi/180)))
                         thetaG= math.acos(thetaG)*(180/math.pi)
                         if not ((thetaG<15 and I1[i,j]+I2[i,j]>0.35) or (thetaG<25 and I1[i,j]+I2[i,j]>0.4)):
                                if math.floor(I4[i,j])==367 and I4Quality[i,j]==9 and I5>290 and I5Quality[i,j]==0 and (I1[i,j]+I2[i,j])>0.7:
                                    points.append([lons[i,j],lats[i,j, 4]])

                                elif I4[i,j]-I5[i,j]>25 or True:
                                    kern = kernMe(i, j, I4)
                                    if kern!=-1 or True:
                                        BT4M = max(325, kern)
                                        kern = min(330, BT4M)
                                        if I4[i,j]> kern and I4[i,j]>avg:
                                            points.append([lons[i,j],lats[i,j], 5])
    return points

if __name__ == '__main__':


    #Separate the arrays into 1616*1600 chunks for multi processing
    #TODO: make this automatic, not hardcoded
    arg=[[0,1616,0,1600],[0,1616,1600,3200],[0,1616,3200,4800],[0,1616,4800,6400],
    [1616,3232,0,1600],[1616,3232,1600,3200],[1616,3232,3200,4800],[1616,3232,4800,6400],
    [3232,4848,0,1600],[3232,4848,1600,3200],[3232,4848,3200,4800],[3232,4848,4800,6400],
    [4848,6464,0,1600],[4848,6464,1600,3200],[4848,6464,3200,4800],[4848,6464,4800,6400]]

    print(arg)
    p=Pool(processes = 4)
    output= p.map(thread_me, arg)
    p.close()
    p.join()

    print(output)

    f.close()
    f2.close()

    logging.info("Aaaand we're here!")
    print(str((time.time()-start)/60))
    p.terminate()
```

I use both p.close and p. terminate because I thought it would help (it doesn't). All of my code runs and produces the expected output but I have to manually end the lingering processes using the task manager. Any ideas as to 
what's causing this?

I think I put all the relevant information here, if you need more I'll edit with the requests

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not my area of expertise, but I would certainly recommend using asyncio instead of multiprocessing. I have used asyncio very successfully for concurrent situations.

Comment: asyncio solves a very different problem to multiprocessing. It's worth being clear on the reasons for choosing one or the other. In this case (which looks like CPU-heavy numpy stuff) then multiprocessing would be more suitable.

Comment: As a first thing to do, I'd move all of the code from `start=time.time()` down to `sensorAz=` into some sort of initialization function. At the moment all that code will be run when each subprocess start up, which might not be what you want.

Comment: As a second thing to do, I'd suspect that the `netCDF4` might be leaving open file handles behind or something that's preventing your workers from closing cleanly. I know that under linux, processes in this state will show up as `[defunct]` but I don't know if there's a Windows-equivalent way to see if a process is in this same stuck-type state.

Comment: Ah, I had assumed that the process would only run the code in the function. I do need the use of the variables that are being read in during the execution of the sub-processes, is there a way to use them without passing them as parameters but also not having them be remade every process? I'll also have to look into the NETCDF4 library, I thought the .close() would remove those file handles but sometimes things don't work as one might think. Thanks for your suggestions